# Composer conflicts and Symfony 3

Tags: php, composer-php, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony

I'm totally new to composer and symfony, and i've started a symfony3 project. Things where going well, but now composer won't update my dependancies. I've been searching a solution for 3 hours.

Here is my console log:

```
  Problem 1
- sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/block-bundle 3.x-dev@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/block-bundle[3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/block-bundle 3.x-dev@dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/block-bundle[3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master].
```

And my composer.json requirements:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

If you can find the problem, and explain it to me, you're going to be my hero!

Comment: Add min stability = dev in your composer.json file: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability

Comment: Never ever ever use `dev-master` as a version constraint. Use `3.0.*@dev` instead or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, composer installs only stable versions of packages, even if you ask a `dev` version for one of them, by defining the [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) to `stable`.

To tell composer that you allow installation of development versions (such as `dev-master`),
Add  the following line after your requirements:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

**Note:**  It's actually mandatory to work with last versions of sonata bundles.